# Mysql container can not run

Tags: mysql, docker

I want to make my own mysql container from mysql image. But mysql container can not run.
My Dockerfile;

```
FROM mysql

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass

RUN mkdir /usr/sql

RUN chmod 644 /usr/sql

ADD Tedam_Master.sql /usr/sql/

ADD restoredb.sh /usr/sql/

ADD entrypoint.sh /usr/sql

RUN chmod +x /usr/sql/restoredb.sh

RUN chmod +x /usr/sql/entrypoint.sh

EXPOSE 3306

WORKDIR /usr/sql/

ENTRYPOINT entrypoint.sh
```

entypoint.sh;

```
/usr/sql/restoredb.sh && /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

restoredb.sh;

```
sleep 10s
echo “Starting database import!”
mysql -u root -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD -e “CREATE DATABASE mydb”
mysql -u root -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD -D mydb< /usr/sql/Tedam_Master.sql
```

Who can help me? At the same time mysql should run and restore database. How can I do?

Comment: check `docker logs container-id`

Comment: There is no error or exception on container log. Firstly mysql service is running after starting restore. But after restore, container was stoped.

Comment: Can you not just use this solution to restore everything: https://medium.com/@lvthillo/customize-your-mysql-database-in-docker-723ffd59d8fb ?

Comment: It didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some modification in docket file. Whenever face some sort of issue always run your docker with -it instead of -d.
I tried to run MySQL from entry point as you mention but have some permission issue `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)` and mysql stop check for self. This will work. And also mysql docker version.

check this getting this issue with your configurations.

https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/302

```
    FROM mysql:5.5

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass

RUN mkdir /usr/sql

RUN chmod 644 /usr/sql
RUn usermod -d /var/lib/mysql/ mysql
ADD Tedam_Master.sql /usr/sql/

ADD restoredb.sh /usr/sql/restoredb.sh

ADD entrypoint.sh /usr/sql/entrypoint.sh

RUN chmod +x /usr/sql/restoredb.sh

RUN chmod +x /usr/sql/entrypoint.sh

EXPOSE 3306

WORKDIR /usr/sql/

# ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sql/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["mysqld"]
```

For restoredb you can run after bootup or if docker compose put them in command section of yml file.

```
docker exec -it test bash -c "/usr/sql/restoredb.sh"
```

**Update:**

The error you mention happens when password not set. Pls, check ENV value in the container. Its good practice to pass ENV at container runtime so I tried with something like this.

```
docker run --rm   --name db  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=abc123 -it db
```

And I don't have your DB restore script. I run a script which just updates time zone.

```
    #!/bin/sh
echo '********Welcome to Docker*******'
echo '********Booting up and connect db container time:20s*******'
sleep 10s
DBSERVER=localhost
USER=root
PASS=pass
MYSQL_CONN="-h${DBSERVER} -u${USER} -p${PASS}"
SQL="SET GLOBAL time_zone='US/Eastern'"
if mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQL}"; then
SQL="SELECT @@global.time_zone"
res=`mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe "${SQL}"`
echo "Time zone update to" $res  ;
else
echo "Failed to update timezone check log"
fi
```

Here is a screenshot. pls check env and try to connect manually first with `mysql -u root -p`

[image]

**update 2 import DB: use this script istead your**

```
#!/bin/sh

    sleep 10s
    DBSERVER=localhost

USER=root
PASS=27940001
MYSQL_CONN="-h${DBSERVER} -u${USER} -p${PASS}"
SQL="create database testdb"
if mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQL}"; then
SQL="show databases"
res=`mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe "${SQL}"`
echo "Database created list of DB's is " $res  ;
mysql -u root -p27940001 -h localhost testdb < test.sql
else
echo "Failed to to create db"
fi
```

**Sample db import script test.sql**

*copy it in dockerfile*

```
copy test.sql /usr/sql/test.sql

    --
-- Database: `samplevideo_db`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `user_details`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_details` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10001 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `user_details`
--

INSERT INTO `user_details` (`user_id`, `username`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `gender`, `password`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 'rogers63', 'david', 'john', 'Female', 'e6a33eee180b07e563d74fee8c2c66b8', 1),
(2, 'mike28', 'rogers', 'paul', 'Male', '2e7dc6b8a1598f4f75c3eaa47958ee2f', 1),
(3, 'rivera92', 'david', 'john', 'Male', '1c3a8e03f448d211904161a6f5849b68', 1),
(4, 'ross95', 'maria', 'sanders', 'Male', '62f0a68a4179c5cdd997189760cbcf18', 1),
(5, 'paul85', 'morris', 'miller', 'Female', '61bd060b07bddfecccea56a82b850ecf', 1),
(6, 'smith34', 'daniel', 'michael', 'Female', '7055b3d9f5cb2829c26cd7e0e601cde5', 1),
(7, 'james84', 'sanders', 'paul', 'Female', 'b7f72d6eb92b45458020748c8d1a3573', 1),
(8, 'daniel53', 'mark', 'mike', 'Male', '299cbf7171ad1b2967408ed200b4e26c', 1),
(9, 'brooks80', 'morgan', 'maria', 'Female', 'aa736a35dc15934d67c0a999dccff8f6', 1),
(10, 'morgan65', 'paul', 'miller', 'Female', 'a28dca31f5aa5792e1cefd1dfd098569', 1);
```

Comment: Hi Adiii, it worked. But I wanted, both of them work with Dockerfile.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't see. Yes I can do it with docker-compose. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Adiii again. It doesn't work when I used into docker-compose file. I took same error.  ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Comment: There is restore db script above.

Comment: Can you help me? I didn't do it. @Adiii

Comment: sorry i was offline check update one u script was wrong

Comment: It doesn't work again. I am doing same things but it didn't work. I am trying with docker-compose file.

Comment: Will you help me?

Comment: You still stuck?  update your question what u did so far

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem.  docker-compose file is;

```
version: "2"

services:
  mysql1:
    build:
      context: .
    image: my-mysql:1.0
    container_name: mysql1
    hostname: mysql1
    environment:
      - 'MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass'
      - 'MYSQL_DATABASE=test'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
  mysqlinit:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes:
      - ./Tedam_Master.sql:/usr/sql/Tedam_Master.sql
    command: bash -c "sleep 15s && mysql -h mysql1 -uroot -ppass --force test < /usr/sql/Tedam_Master.sql"
```

I used two mysql image.Second one is restoring to first one. It worked for me. Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Could be unrelated since I'm using `docker-compose` and my service is bundled in a laravel project but turns out my problem was trying to define the user as `root`.

If this doesn't work for you, try getting to the root of the problem by doing `docker logs <container ID>`. To get the container ID do `docker ps -a`.

Regards